# Corollary of Borel-Cantelli lemma

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Measure space $(X, \mathcal{A}, ν)$ has $ν(X) = 1$. Let $A_n \in  \mathcal{A} $ and denote

$B := \{x : x ∈ A_n$ for infinitly many n }.

I want to prove that if  $ν(A_n) \geq \epsilon > 0$ for all n, then $ν(B) ≥ \epsilon$.

$\textbf{My attempt}:$

$$B = \text{limsup} A_n = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k$$
taking complement and taking measure from both sides:
$$\nu(X)-\nu(B) =  \nu\bigg[\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigg(\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k\bigg)^c\bigg] = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \nu(B_n)\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty\nu(B_n)$$
$$\nu(B) \geq 1 - \sum_{n=1}^\infty\nu(B_n) $$

$B_n$ is an increasing sequence (i.e.$B_n \subset B_{n+1}$)  ,right?

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\nu(B_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty}\nu(B_n)$ so there exist N such that $\nu(B_n) \leq \frac{1-\epsilon}{2^n}$ thus;

$$\nu(B) \geq 1 - \sum_{n=1}^\infty\nu(B_n) \leq 1-(1-\epsilon)=\epsilon $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true that $\sum \nu (B_n)=\lim \nu(B_n)$. Also the inequality you derived is of no use when  $\sum \nu (B_n)=\infty$ because it just says $\nu (B) \geq -\infty$.

For a correct proof use Fatou's Lemma:

$\nu(B^{c})=\nu (\lim \inf A_n^{c}) \leq \lim \inf \nu (A_n^{c})\leq 1-\epsilon$ so $\nu (B) \geq \epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

You have some mistakes in your proof. Here is a simple one.

Let $B_n=\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k$

$\nu(B_n)\geq \nu(A_n) \geq \epsilon, \forall n \in \Bbb{N}$

Then $\nu(B)=\lim_n \nu(B_n) \geq \epsilon$

Comment: I defined $B_n =\bigg( \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k\bigg)^c$ .

Comment: I  know..i defined $B_n$ differently,and with this way you have your conclusion